# Palindrome Index

Tags: java, algorithm

We are given a String `S`, determine the index of the character whose removal will make `S` palindrome. For example, if we have `"bcbc"`, we can either remove `b` at index `0`  or `c` at index `3` . Print the index of the character whose removal makes the string palindrome.

I implemented the following code:

```
public class Solution {

public static boolean checkPalindrome(String str, int start1, int end1 ){
    int start = start1;
    int end = end1 - 1;
    int half = end/2;
    for(int i = 0; i < half; i++, start++, end-- ){
         if(str.charAt(start) != str.charAt(end))
            return false;

    }
    return true;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int test=sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    while(test-->0){
        String str=sc.nextLine();
        int i=0;
        int j=str.length()-1;

        if(checkPalindrome(str, 0, str.length())){
            System.out.println("-1");
        }
        else{
        while(i<j){
            if(str.charAt(i)!=str.charAt(j)){// checks if char at j and i are not same
                if(str.charAt(i+1)==str.charAt(j)){//if not same then check for char at i+1 , eg cbcb: 0 and 3 are not same, so check for 1 and 3. If they are same then check if the string from new position is palindrome. If it is then 0 is the position to be removed. else not possible as you are to only remove once
                    if(checkPalindrome(str,i+1,j)){
                        System.out.println(i);
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                       System.out.println("-1");
                        break;
                    }

                }
                else if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(j-1)){//same as above but now for j.

                    if(checkPalindrome(str,i,j-1)){
                        System.out.println(j);
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                       System.out.println("-1");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            i++;
            j--;
        }
        }
       /* else{
            System.out.println("not palindrome");
        }*/
    }
}
}
```

But the problem is I am not able to find where I am wrong. Can anyone figure out the error in my code.

Comment: What is the output of your program? What output are you expecting? Can you explain your code with comments? It is seemingly unnecessarily complex. Furthermore, is `while(test-->0)` a typo or some new operator I am not aware of?

Comment: This is not a typo, It is a valid syntax.
For example:
`Input :`
`1`
`quyjjdcgsvvsgcdjjyq`
`Output:`
`8`

Comment: My bad. I was viewing it as an arrow pointing to the right. Brainfart.

Comment: I have given the example input.

Comment: I am first taking the string, checking it whether it is palindrome or not, if it is then print "-1" else find the index of the char whose removal makes the remaining string palindrome.

Comment: Please show us the expected output, and the actual output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's wrong with your solution, but it really seems overly complicated.

Here's a much simplified solution that works.

**Note**: I use your `checkPalindrome` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    /*
     * Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT.
     * Your class should be named Solution.
     */
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a String to check:");
    String str = sc.nextLine();

    // go through the entire string a check if each string with the ith 
    // index removed
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        String possiblePalin = str.substring(0,i) + str.substring(i+1);
        System.out.println("Checking: " + possiblePalin);

        if (checkPalindrome(possiblePalin, 0, possiblePalin.length()))
        {
            System.out.println("Removing the char at index: " + i + " makes your stirng a Palindrome");
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample Run**:

> ```
> Enter a String to check:
> bcbc
> Checking: cbc
> Removing the char at index: 0 makes your stirng a Palindrome
> Checking: bbc
> Checking: bcc
> Checking: bcb
> Removing the char at index: 3 makes your stirng a Palindrome
> ```

Comment: You only need to print only one possibility. Anyways this is a neat solution. But I was wondering what was the error in my code.

Comment: Then you can simply put a `break` in the if statement.

Comment: Your code is just hard to read. Maybe add some comments in the code to explain what you are doing and where you think the problem might occur.

Comment: Also your code is quite time consuming as you are checking every possible string. @Michael

Comment: @ShubamSinghJamwal You have to check every possible string with 1 char removed. How else would you do the algorithm? Please let me know if I'm missing something.